# ListView cambiar orden en el que muestra

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview

Tengo un listview que coge datos de Firebase, el problema es que me muestra los últimos datos introducidos en la parte inferior de manera que si fuera una pila almacena los datos de abajo a arriba.

Codigo en Java del Activity:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
Button btnDelete;
Module3 module;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_reservas);

    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reservas");
    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewReservas);
    //btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrarElemento);
    arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(Reservas.class).toString();
            arrayList.add(value);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Este es el xml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de como se muestra el listView:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De abajo hacia arriba pero de que campo? ,  en la imagen no se ve muy claro cual sería el campo en base a cual deseas el ordenamiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para invertir el orden en el que se muestra, mediante: **Collections.reverse(arrayList);**

```
...arrayList.add(value);
            Collections.reverse(arrayList);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();....
```